# While loop waiting for input python

Tags: python, input, while-loop, pygame

I have a question about while loops in python.
I want to make a program that performs a while loop in a certain time.I want to add the extra feature that while the program us running,a certain variable can be changed by pressing a random key.

```
   from time import sleep
   import time
   i=0
   a=0
   while i<10:
       i=i+1
       i=i+a
       a=a+1
       time.sleep(1)
      print i
```

I want to do it that the variable a can be reset to 0 by pressing any key.The loop should continue unchanged if no button is pressed.What command should i add?

Thanks
Edit: I tried:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time

i=0
a=0
pygame.init()
while i<10:
    pygame.event.get()
    i=i+a
    print i
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
               i=0
    i=i+1
    time.sleep(1)
 pygame.quit()
```

But now nothing happens when I press a button.What did i miss?

Comment: Seems to me that you'll need a thread to do something like this -- Plus an implementation of `getch`. (recipes are floating around SO for that one).  1 thread calls getch and updates the variable when it sees some data.  The other thread runs your while loop.

Comment: Here is a recipe http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a non-blocking input function

```
while i<10:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    etc
    ...
```

pygame has all sorts of event stuff built in so doing all the hard work of threading yourself shouldn't be necessary.

If that doesn't work for you check this out: http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/

Answer (score 0):

You can use curses.Excellent doc is here: 
http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html#user-input