# How to make while loop keep going while still looking for input in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

I am making a Cookie clicker like game in Python, and I am trying to have the while loop keep going so it checks if a second has gone (so it adds "cookies") while still looking if the user is making an input (clicking on "Cookie").

Whenever I try this it waits for the input instead of doing the rest of the loop.

This is what my current code looks like (There's more of course):

```
While True:
    console.clear()
    cookieText = "You have " + str(cookies) + " cookies"
    print cookieText
    clicker = raw_input("")
    if clicker == "":
        cookies += clickerPower
    more...
```

This is what I want to add:

```
While True:
    last = time()
    if last == timer:
        timer = last
        more...
```

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: You have to share code or part of it or pseudo code to get help on this

Comment: possibly you can get your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13034175/1330355

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input))

```
import msvcrt

num = 0
done = False
while not done:
    print num
    num += 1

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        print msvcrt.getch()
        done = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). But it's not simple.